# How to check if a point is between two other points, but not limited to be aligned on a straight line?

Tags: math, geometry, coordinates

I need to check if a lat-lon coordinate (`A`) is between two other lat-lon coordinates (`B` and `C`). However, the point `A` doesn't have to be on the line `B->C`.
Refer to this picture, where `A` should be counted as "between" `B` and `C`:

[image]

How can I do this calculation?

***PS:*** The locations can be converted to SWEREF99TM, which is a grid system, if that is better for calculating with. I already have the formula for that conversion.

Comment: Please define 'in between' more clearly.  Does it include all points between the drawn lines including very distant points from B and C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming we're on a plane and not a sphere, even though you mentioned lattitude/longitude...

A is "between" B and C if angle ∠ABC and angle ∠ACB are both less than or equal to ninety degrees.

Handily, we don't even need trigonometry to detect this; an angle ∠PQR is greater than ninety degrees iff PQ^2 + QR^2 < QR^2.

```
def lies_between(A,B,C):
    a = distance(B,C)
    b = distance(C,A)
    c = distance(A,B)
    return a**2 + b**2 >= c**2 and a**2 + c**2 >= b**2

def distance(A,B):
    return math.sqrt((A.x - B.x)**2 + (A.y - B.y)**2)
```

(Where `**` is the exponentiation operator.)

Comment: On second look, this approach might work for spherical geometry too... Not sure if it behaves properly for nearly-antipodal B and C points.

Comment: This doesn't work as required... See the code I'm using here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6525fc5fbac28116a93a

Comment: Oops, my apologies. My `return` statement was wrong - it was inspecting angle BAC instead of angle ABC. Edited.

Comment: After the modification, this works perfectly! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is basically take the projection of A onto BC.  It's unintuitive but simple, being the most obvious application of dot products.

You can read the math here...
http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/dotprod/dotprod.html

Let `dot(x, y)` be the dot product of two tuples and `vec(x, y)` be the vector from x to y. Then your answer is just...

```
// Dot product
dot = lambda d1,d2: sum(a*b for a,b in zip(d1,d2))

// Vector between two points
vec = lambda d1,d2: tuple(b-a for a,b in zip(d1,d2))

BA=vec(b,a)
BC=vec(b,c)

BA_scalar = dot(BA, BC) / dot(BC, BC) # BA * BC / |BC|
# BA_scalar = 0 means A is co-planar with B
# BA_scalar = 1 means A is co-planar with C

is_between = 0 < BA_scalar and BA_scalar < 1
```

This works for both 3d and 2d coordinates.  It leads to interesting results in 3d though, for example all equatorial points lie inbetween 10°N, 0° and 10°S, 0°, including ones on the opposite end of the globe.  That's not necessarily wrong though.